# create multidimensional array then push another array each those multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, multidimensional-array

is that possible to create a multidimensional array, then push another array on each those multidimensional array ?? 
lets say the variable

```
arr = ["apple", "orange",  "Avocados", "Tomato", "Tangerine"]
```

and the output I want is:

```js
[
  ["a", ["apple", "avocados"] ], 
  [ "o", ["orange"] ], 
  ["T", ["Tomato", "Tangering"]]
]
```

the example about to create first initial to new arr multidimensional before the output, we create like this,  `[[ "a"],["o"],["T"]]` and output i want is on above ( the box code )

then check again if that first initial same with a first initial array, push it on those 2d arrays, that is for example, but if array length for others is not same, we should create a function, to use it again late

Comment: does the case matters? the given data does not match the wanted output. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: the output i want is on the box @NinaScholz

Comment: are you sure that's the output you want? I think this output format is much better :
{
  "a" : ["apple", "avocados"], 
  "o": ["orange"], 
  "t": ["Tomato", "Tangering"]
}

Comment: yes i am sure, if the output like you said, I think it would be good also, can u give me the example for output like that ?? @EricMarcelino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group the data by finding the array with the value or create a new array for the result set.

```js
var array = ["apple", "orange", "avocados", "tomato", "tangerine"],
    result = array.reduce((r, s) => {
        var temp = r.find(([c]) => c === s[0]);
        if (temp) {
            temp[1].push(s);
        } else {
            r.push([s[0], [s]]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A better structure would be to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect all strings to the same starting letter.

```js
var array = ["apple", "orange", "avocados", "tomato", "tangerine"],
    result = Array.from(
        array.reduce((map, s) => map.set(s[0], [...(map.get(s[0]) || []), s]), new Map)
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your output is too complicated to produce. You can simplify the output format like this:

```
{
   "a" : ["apple", "avocados"], 
   "o": ["orange"], 
   "t": ["Tomato", "Tangering"] 
 }
```

You can produce output like this with ease with Lodash:

```
_.groupBy(["apple", "orange",  "Avocados", "Tomato", "Tangerine"], function (item) {
  return item[0].toLowerCase()
});
```

Or with iterate the array:

```
var arr = ["apple", "orange",  "Avocados", "Tomato", "Tangerine"];
var output = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
  if (output[arr[i][0].toLowerCase()] == undefined)
    output[arr[i][0].toLowerCase()] = [];
  output[arr[i][0].toLowerCase()].push(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array to object

```js
var arr = ["apple", "orange",  "Avocados", "Tomato", "Tangerine"];

var output = arr.reduce(function(res, item) {
  if(Object.keys(res).indexOf(item.charAt(0).toLowerCase()) == -1) 
  {
    res[item.charAt(0).toLowerCase()] = [];
  }
  res[item.charAt(0).toLowerCase()].push(item);
  return res;
},{});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative using vanilla JavaScript and some functional programming:

```js
const input = ["apple", "orange", "Avocados", "Tomato", "Tangerine"]

// (1) An unique list of lower-cased initials of all given input words
// * Set gives us the unique behavior
const initials = [...new Set (
      input.map (([initial]) => initial.toLowerCase ())
)]

const byInitial = ([initial]) => ([initial_]) => 
      initial_.toLowerCase () == initial

// (2) This groups each world by their initial
// Iterates each lowered initial and filters the input by each initial 
// to build the groups!
const grouped = initials.reduce ((o, initial) =>
    [
      ...o, // <--- this accumulates the new result with the previous one
      [
        initial, 
        input.filter (byInitial(initial))
      ]
    ], [])
    
console.log (grouped)
```

#### Yet another approach, now using `zip`:

```js
const input = ["apple", "orange", "Avocados", "Tomato", "Tangerine"]

// (1) An unique list of lower-cased initials of all given input words
// * Set gives us the unique behavior
const initials = [...new Set (
      input.map (([initial]) => initial.toLowerCase ())
)]

const byInitial = ([initial]) => ([initial_]) => 
      initial_.toLowerCase () == initial

// (2) This builds groups each world by their initial
const groups = initials.map (initial => 
      input.filter (byInitial (initial))
)

const zip = (xs, ys) => 
      xs.map((x, i) => [x, ys[i]])
      
// zip builds the pairs, where each one is the initial and the group
const grouped = zip (initials, groups)
    
console.log (grouped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), create an object with first `char` of each item as the `key` and an array of all the items which start with that char as it's `value`. Then call [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the desired output:

```js
const arr = ["apple", "orange",  "avocados", "tomato", "tangerine"],
group = Object.entries(arr.reduce((a, i) => ((a[i[0]] = a[i[0]] || []).push(i), a), {}));

console.log(group);
```